# How to get an XML file via HTTP when Jenkins runs Codeception

Tags: jenkins

Our developers develop in Virtualbox VMs which have a web server configured to point at the codebase they are working on. When they run Codeception tests, the code calls the local web server requesting a data file from within the codebase and proceeds with the test. Works well.

The problem I'm running into is running the tests on our Jenkins Server (using a Declarative Pipeline, if that matters). Jenkins installs the code in a temporary directory (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/). Obviously I can't point the web server on Jenkins to point to the temp directory (especially when I'm building different branches in different temporary directories) so the tests fail when trying to fetch the data file.

The reason we fetch the data file via HTTP is because the code we are testing does precisely that in production; fetches code from another web server not under our control and we want to mimic the functionality in our test.

How should this be handled? Copy the data files to a common directory outside of Jenkins that the web server points to? If so, how do I handle different developers using the same data file with different values? Or do I just tell them "Don't do that?"

Any suggestions?

Comment: You just want to test the fetching from an application server? Why don't you store it on a separate location for testing purposes? To make the test realistic it should be independent from your Jenkins server.

Comment: That's a good point. To keep things in lock-step, I'll have to have my Declarative Pipeline on the Jenkins server execute a command on the remote server to pull down the XML files.